# streaming multiple records from sql query in android view

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have written a game for the android platform using Xamarin.  This is an online game. Where all players are playing against each other.  It's a simple points calculation that will decide who is winning.

Of course all player points are stored in a database and I will be using an sql query to get top scores on a real time basis.  I do not want to use any other platform except my own mysql database on my own server (no amazon, google or azure).

My question is what would be the easiest way to create a horizontally scrolling ticker showing top 75 scores something like a dow jones ticker scrolling across the bottom of the screen.

In my mind it should be some kind of stream of multiple records from a query.

Comment: Hi, by `horizontally scrolling ticker`, I can't understand what it is, can you show me a picture about that or anything can explain it?

Comment: If you look at any financial page showing the dow jones index.  you will see company names and stock values scrolling horizontally across a screen.

Comment: Broken line graph? Like [this](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/djia)? And it should be dynamic?